# Inline div with nowrap and overflow hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, stylesheet

I have a top bar with multiple `div` inside. It works as expected in Chrome but in Firefox, the `.third` div got wrapped around in a second row. How to make the `.third` div in Firefox to have `nowrap` like Chrome?

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/C6f4c/

Here are the conditions:

1. `.top` always have `width:100%` so it covers the whole browser window
2. Each inner `divs` (first, second, third...) have their own predefined fixed width
3. They must stay in **one row**. And if the browse width is not enough, the ones on the right will be overflow hidden (not wrap into second line).
4. Prefer to handle this with css. jQuery should be last resort.

Help is appreciate!!

Comment: Is it wrapped because of the width?

Comment: @244an, now sure which "width" you mean. But all parent divs should have max width of the browser (100%) and child divs will have their fixed widths.

Comment: I meant if the wrapping was caused by long texts. But never mind, I saw that @Cadence96 solved it. I also use `display: inline-block` in Firefox when nesting divs etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the float:left from your inner divs an add display:inline-block. Those divs will act as inline elements but with the same block properties.

http://jsfiddle.net/C6f4c/2/

```
.top {
  width: 100%; /* this is optional to accomplish your first condition, either you don't need to have inline-block on this element */

}
.top div {
    position: relative;
    /*float: left;*/
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Was just about to say this same exact thing.

Comment: Great. What a dump mistake on my part

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using media queries? You can hide a div once the browser reaches a certain max width etc.

More here:

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/